# Magento htaccess redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, mod-rewrite

I was trying to redirect a particular URL and all its child URL's to a particular URL. Using 301 redirection this is working fine but the browser URL is showing the test contents also. Please see below for more details

Example: `https://www.mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/referer/*` needs to be redirected towards `https://www.mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/register`

What I tried is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /customer/account/login/referer  https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/register
```

The htaccess rule is working fine for just this URL. If I type

```
https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/referer/testing
```

This will be redirected towards `https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/register/test`

Please let me know how I will be able to trim the other part (URL part after register/*)from the redirected URL. What I am trying to achieve is

`https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/referer/*` [ANY URL's AFTER referer/ (Including /referer) needs to be redirected to `https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/register`].

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour, as stated in the documentation of [`Redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

> Then any request beginning with URL-Path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. **Additional path information beyond the matched URL-Path will be appended to the target URL.**

To redirect all requests starting with this prefix to the given URL, you may use [`RedirectMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch), which uses regular expressions instead of a URL prefix

```
RedirectMatch ^/customer/account/login/referer https://mywebsite.com/customer/account/login/register
```

---

You don't need to use

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
```

because this is for mod_rewrite. `Redirect` and `RedirectMatch` are provided by the mod_alias module.

Comment: Thank you Olaf. This worked great. Exactly what i was trying to achieve. Now all the URL's are redirecting based on the request.  Also thank you for the detailed explanation.